optimization based on complex matrix differentiation
I'm calculating the gradient of a loss function with respect to some complex matrices. The loss function is defined as $\mathcal{L}=||I(x)-\widetilde{I}(x)||_2^2$, where $I(x)$ is the output from a mathematical model, and $\widetilde{I}(x)$ is the observation data.
Specifically,
$I(x)=w_1|E_1(x)|^2 + w_2|E_2(x)|^2 + w_3[E_1^*(x)E_2(x)+E_1(x)E_2^*(x)]$,
where $^*$ denotes complex conjugate. $w_1$, $w_2$, and $w_3$ are scalar real value.
In addition,
$E_1(x)=\mathcal{F}[P_1(X)e^{i\phi(X)}]$ and $E_2(x)=\mathcal{F}[P_2(X)e^{i\phi(X)}]$,
where $\mathcal{F}$ denotes the Fourier transform.
In the above formulas, $I$ and $\phi$ are real matrices. $E$ and $P$ are complex matrices.
So, how can I calculate the gradient of the loss function $\mathcal{L}$ with respect to $P_1(X)$ and $P_2(X)$, respectively?
I derived the gradient as
$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial P_1(X)} = e^{-i\phi(X)}\mathcal{F}^{-1}\{2[2w_1E_1(x)+w_3E_2(x)][I(x)-\widetilde{I}(x)]\} + e^{i\phi(X)}\mathcal{F}\{2w_3E_2^*(x)[I(x)-\widetilde{I}(x)]\}$
Is it correct? Moreover, I'm curious whether I should include the gradient to the complex conjugate of $E_1^*(x)$, which corresponds to the second term in the above formula.

Here's how you can calculate the Wirtinger derivative of the loss function, assuming that you are using a (Fast) Fourier Transform.
$
\def\s{\odot}
\def\h{\odot}
\def\VV#1{\Big\vert #1\Big\vert}
\def\VV#1{\left\vert #1\right\vert}
{\sf NB\!:}\ $I implemented your $\VV{X}^2$ operation as
$$\eqalign{
&\VV{X}^2 = X^*\h X
}$$
where $\h$ denotes the Hadamard product.

$
\def\L{{\cal L}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\bR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\KR#1{\left\{#1\right\}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\F{{\large\mathbb F}}
\def\Fi{{\large\mathbb F}^{-1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\red#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\blue#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\red{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fft#1{\op{\blue{FFT}}\KR{#1}}
\def\ifft#1{\op{\blue{iFFT}}\LR{#1}}
$First, define the Frobenius product (denoted by a colon)
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
B^*\!:B &= \frob{B}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in such products to be rearranged in many useful ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
&A:B = B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
&A:\LR{B\h C} = \LR{A\h B}:C \\
&A:\LR{XY} = \LR{AY^T}:X \;=\; \LR{X^TA}:Y \\
&A:\fft B = \fft A:B \\\\
}$$

Next, calculate the differential of the $E_2(x)$ function
$$\eqalign{
\def\e{e^{i\phi}}
M &= \e,
 \q E_2 = \fft{P_2M} \qiq dE_2 = \fft{dP_2\:M} \\\\
}$$

Then the differential of $I(x)$ with respect to $E_2$
$$\eqalign{
\def\A{{\large\alpha}}
\def\B{{\large\beta}}
\def\G{{\large\Omega}}
I &= w_1E_1^*\s E_1 + w_2E_2^*\s\red{E_2}
   + w_3E_1^*\red{E_2} + w_3E_1 E_2^* \\
dI
 &= w_2E_2^*\s\red{dE_2}  + w_3E_1^*\ \red{dE_2} \\
}$$

Then the differential of the loss function wrt $P_2$
$$\eqalign{
\def\I{\widetilde{I}}
J &= (I-\I) \qiq dJ=dI \\
\L &= J:J \\
d\L &= 2J:\red{dJ} \\
 &= 2J:\bR{ w_2E_2^*\s\red{dE_2}  + w_3E_1^*\ \red{dE_2} } \\
 &= 2\bR{J\h w_2E_2^* + w_3E_1^HJ}:\red{dE_2} \\
 &= 2\bR{J\h w_2E_2^* + w_3E_1^HJ}:\fft{dP_2\:M} \\
 &= 2\,\fft{J\h w_2E_2^* + w_3E_1^HJ}:\LR{dP_2\:M} \\
 &= 2\,\fft{J\h w_2E_2^* + w_3E_1^HJ}\,M^T:dP_2 \\
}$$
where $\,E_1^H$ denotes the hermitian conjugate


Now the gradient (in the Wirtinger sense) can be identified as
$$\eqalign{
\grad\L{P_2}
 &= 2\,\fft{(I-\I)\h w_2E_2^* + w_3E_1^H(I-\I)}\,\LR{\e}^T \\
}$$
The calculation for ${\grad\L{P_1}}$ is similar.

I wonder if the conjugate of E_2 should be considered when differentiating with respect to E_2?

@XinLiu  I've added links for the Wirtinger Derivative at the top of the post.
